# Change sqlite to use machine's TZ and not GMT

Tags: sqlite, timezone

Is there a way to change `sqlite` to use my machine's TZ instead of GMT ?  `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is currently displaying GMT.  I need it as the default value for a record timestamp column.

Comment: while that solves the problem with one table, it doesn't do it across the whole application.  so it partially answers it

Comment: It solves it for every date/time call in the database. What else do you want? (And you asked for one table ...)

Comment: i wanted to set CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to always be localtime